# Importing oracle dump file, getting error on stored procedures

Tags: oracle, export, import, stored-procedures

I export an oracle "schema" using

```
exp userid=/ file=pt.dmp log=pt.log owner=FOO buffer=10000000 statistics=NONE direct=Y
```

and then import it into a different schema on the same oracle instance on the same SID using

```
imp userid=/ file=pt.dmp fromuser=FOO touser=paul
```

When I try to access the stored procedures, I get

```
ORA-29541: class PAUL.ESMQOracleStoredProc could not be resolved
```

Any idea why one user can resolve this but another one can't?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need "FULL" on the export. see this url:

[link text](http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/tutorial/Oracle-data-export-guide#)

Comment: You can't use FULL with FROMUSER.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any failures in the import ?
Possibly an object didn't get created or replaced (maybe an object with the same name already existed).

Comment: Nope.  As a matter of fact, when I browse the database using SQLDeveloper, I can see the stored procedures there.